# How to configure Spring JPA to prevent it disclosing schema informations

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

At work we manage a REST API developed in Spring MVC.

It also use the JPA + Spring Repositories modules to implement CRUD like endpoints over a database.

For security matters, we've been asked to prevent the returned error messages, I.E. 500 ones mostly, from disclosing the underlying architecture, such as the database kind, certain schema informations, and such

By any chance, are such considerations already managed thanks a "magical" Spring configuration parameter ?

If not, I'm looking for any advise about the way to manage this

So far, the best I've thought about is to setup a `@ControllerAdvice` in order to catch all the Spring JPA exception messages that could arise during request processing, and hide their messages away by replacing them on the fly.

I haven't implemented such a solution so far, but at first glance, it feels a bit awkward to manage it that way ...

Answer (score 0):

Please read this https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring. All exception-handling methods are mentioned here and you can choose the best one.

I personally like **Solution 3: @ControllerAdvice** and **7. Spring Boot Support**